# Pocketing the striker while covering the Queen

Tags: carrom

Say I'm white, and the board has 1 white, 3 black and 1 Queen left on it.

I pocket the Queen. Then, when covering the Queen, I pocket both the remaining white piece along with the striker.

What is the outcome?

Comment: Think you've used the wrong tag.

Comment: Please suggest and guide me in carom rules

Comment: Mr Samthere yes ur right. But what will be outcome ?

Answer (score 0):

**Two of your pocketed pieces are removed and placed on the board. You continue playing, trying to cover the queen.**

I'm referring to the [ICF Laws of Carrom](http://icf-media.beepworld.de/laws-of-carrom.htm):

> 101) a) While covering the Queen by a proper stroke, if a player pockets the striker along with his C/m, the C/m so pocketed plus one C/m as Due shall be taken out for placing by the opponent. The player shall however, continue his turn. If in that subsequent stroke no C/m of the player is pocketed, the Queen shall not be considered to have been covered and it shall be taken out for placing.